# How to know which Bluetooth 5 feature my iPhone is compatible with?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

A device can be branded as "Bluetooth 5.0" even if the device is not compatible with all Bluetooth 5 features since they are optional; some of these features are :

- High Speed (LE 2M)
- Long range (PHY Coded)
- Extended advertisement

For android device, we can view the device bluetooth features compatibility using nRF Connect App. Unfortunately, this feature does not exist on iOS nFR Connect App.

I tried to find more information on iPhone 8 tech specs's page (https://support.apple.com/kb/SP767?locale=en_US), but this page is just referring "Bluetooth 5.0 wireless technology". However it seems that iPhone 8 does not support extended Advertisement, but how can I get this information (official doc, Core Bluetooth)?

Where can I get Apple devices compatibility details on Bluetooth 5 further than just a "Bluetooth 5.0. Compatible" ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Does an iOS device is High Speed (LE 2M) compatible, does an iOS device is Long range (PHY Coded) compatible, does an iOS device is Extended advertisement compatible ?

Comment: my answer helped to you or should i elaborate somethings more ?

Comment: Thank you for your post @zeytin, unfortunately this is not helping in my case.
If I have to summarise my question, it would be : How can I get detail bluetooth specification for a given iOS device ? It could be official apple documentation, or even commands/methods from CoreBluetooth.

Comment: i see i think it is useful that would be nice if you upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I could not find official document yet but There are a good many useful information related your question [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/tags/core-bluetooth://). One of them is :

> Bluetooth 5.0 compliance allows for leaving out various features of Bluetooth 5.0 and still being compliant.  One of the features left out of a lot of chipsets now supporting 5.0 is 125-kbps Coded Bluetooth radio TX/RX.  This is where the physical lay of radio transmits a lower bitrate, more energy per bit, with FEC (Forward Error Correction).  This is what allows for the long range feature of BT 5.0.  I could find the larger advertising packets, higher speed features of BT 5.0 in the Bluetooth core but not the method to prefer long range vs data rate in the connection parameters.